# How to build darknet.so files? Obico detection algorithm

Tags: opencv, cmake, build, darknet

I want to run `Obico` detective algorithm in standalone mode, without Docker.

To do that I need to build somehow `darknet` with `YOLO` (on `Obico` site it was written that they use `YOLO 2`) and create `darknet.so` files.

I can't understand how to build it.

I have Mac, and when I just build the latest release of `darknet` by `AlexanderAB` (using make, Cmake, or even Powershell) I can't find any `darknet.so` files.

When I try to build `YOLO V2` I can do it only using "make", so I need to build an older version of OpenCV.

But here comes another problem, when I build the latest version of OpenCV with `homebrew`, it tells me that I need to enable c++11 support.

When I want to build it manually (the latest version) from source files indicating `-CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11`

I don't understand the structure, because I need to provide than `opencv.pc` file , but the structure is very different from the `homebrew` installation.

Than I tried to build some older versions of OpenCV, but I can't build them. Just receive an error, that OpenCV core build error on 25%.

And anyways I won't understand the structure because It will be built from  the older versions of source files.

Any suggestions or ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the build steps on the new Darknet/YOLO repo.  It always builds the DLL/LIB (Windows) and SO (Linux).  There are no build steps for Mac, but I'm guessing it will be very close to the Linux build steps.  The new repo with the instructions:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents